# SQL : Why doesn't this ROWNUMBER function work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  DateErrored
FROM     (SELECT Category, ROW_NUMBER  (Partition by dateerrored ORDER BY category DESC)AS Row FROM AspErrors)
            AS LogWithRowNumbers
WHERE  Row >= 1 AND Row <= 10
```

Comment: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

Answer (score 9):

Change `ROW_NUMBER` to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`.

[Link to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: yup, that would do it (unless he's running sql server 2000)